# Convert NSDate to NSString

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsstring, nsdate

How do I convert, `NSDate` to `NSString` so that only the year in **@"yyyy"** format is output to the string?

Answer (score 475, accepted):

How about...

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

//Optionally for time zone conversions
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myNSDateInstance];

//unless ARC is active
[formatter release];
```

**Swift 4.2 :**

```
func stringFromDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm" //yyyy
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Comment: This will produce a memory leak, since the formatter is never released.

Comment: Don't use `init` with `NSDateFormatter`. It was [removed after iOS 3.2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/init). (And if you use a class method instead, it will autorelease and you won't have the leak problem, too.)

Comment: Really suggest looking below at localizedStringFromDate

Comment: @zekel I'm not sure what the documentation used to say, but now it suggests `init` in multiple places.

Comment: I would have autoreleased it (3 years ago)

Comment: iOS7 uses this pattern for formatting: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 284):

I don't know how we all missed this: *[localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/localizedStringFromDate%3adateStyle%3atimeStyle%3a)*

```
NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date] 
                                                      dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle 
                                                      timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

outputs '13/06/12 00:22:39 GMT+03:00'

Comment: once written out to a string, is there a nice neat way to read it in like this? (using those NSDateFormatter enums)

Comment: @Fonix I don't think so - this is a localized string, which means it depends on the user's locale settings. You should never store dates in a format like this because the settings can change any time.

Comment: Its nice if you use the formatter rare. Otherwise you need a cache.

Comment: In swift: let dateString = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(date, dateStyle: .ShortStyle, timeStyle: .FullStyle);

Comment: Reduced the number of codes and thanks its working perfect

Answer (score 87):

Hope to add more value by providing the normal formatter including the year, month and day with the time.
You can use this formatter for more than just a year

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

Answer (score 25):

there are a number of `NSDate` helpers on the web, I tend to use:

https://github.com/billymeltdown/nsdate-helper/

Readme extract below:

```
  NSString *displayString = [NSDate stringForDisplayFromDate:date];
```

This produces the following kinds of output:

```
‘3:42 AM’ – if the date is after midnight today
‘Tuesday’ – if the date is within the last seven days
‘Mar 1’ – if the date is within the current calendar year
‘Mar 1, 2008’ – else ;-)
```

Comment: This is definitely a great solution.  Don't have to waste time worrying about how you want your dates to look, and can get on with coding. :)

Answer (score 14):

In Swift:

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
var dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(YourNSDateInstanceHERE)
```

Comment: In Swift 3.0

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
return formatter.string(from: date)

Answer (score 8):

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [dateformate setDateFormat:@"yyyy"]; // Date formater
  NSString *date = [dateformate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; // Convert date to string
  NSLog(@"date :%@",date);
```

Comment: "YYYY" gives the year for the current week not day. Use "yyyy" instead. See this SO question for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter

Comment: Thanks Steve moser :)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have `NSDate` `-descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:` available (I don't believe iPhone/Cocoa Touch includes this) you may need to use strftime and monkey around with some C-style strings. You can get the UNIX timestamp from an `NSDate` using `NSDate -timeIntervalSince1970`.

Answer (score 5):

```
+(NSString*)date2str:(NSDate*)myNSDateInstance onlyDate:(BOOL)onlyDate{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    if (onlyDate) {
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    }else{
        [formatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    }

    //Optionally for time zone conversions
    //   [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myNSDateInstance];
    return stringFromDate;
}

+(NSDate*)str2date:(NSString*)dateStr{
    if ([dateStr isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
        return (NSDate*)dateStr;
    }

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add this extension:

```
extension NSDate {
    var stringValue: String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yourDateFormat"
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac OS X you can write:

```
NSString* s = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S" timeZone:nil locale:nil];
```

However this is not available on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

It's swift format :

```
func dateFormatterWithCalendar(calndarIdentifier: Calendar.Identifier, dateFormat: String) -> DateFormatter {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: calndarIdentifier)
    formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat

    return formatter
}


//Usage
let date = Date()
let fotmatter = dateFormatterWithCalendar(calndarIdentifier: .gregorian, dateFormat: "yyyy")
let dateString = fotmatter.string(from: date)
print(dateString) //2018
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 4 answer

```
static let dateformat: String = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
public static func stringTodate(strDate : String) -> Date
{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateformat
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)
    return date!
}
public static func dateToString(inputdate : Date) -> String
{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateformat
    return formatter.string(from: inputdate)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

### **Use `extension` to have clear code**

---

You can write an extension to convert any `Date` object to any desired calendar and any format

```
extension Date{
    func asString(format: String = "yy/MM/dd HH:mm",
                  for identifier: Calendar.Identifier = .persian) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: identifier)
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
let now = Date()

print(now.asString())  // prints -> 00/04/18 20:25
print(now.asString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd"))  // prints -> 1400/04/18
print(now.asString(format: "MM/dd", for: .gregorian))  //  prints -> 07/09
```

To learn how to specify your **desired format** string take a look at this [link](https://nsdateformatter.com/).
For a complete reference on how to format dates see **Apple**'s official **Date Formatting Guide** [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW5).

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to use C# styled way to convert Date to String.

usage:

```
let a = time.asString()
// 1990-03-25


let b = time.asString("MM ∕ dd ∕ yyyy, hh꞉mm a")
// 03 / 25 / 1990, 10:33 PM
```

extensions:

```
extension Date {
    func asString(_ template: String? = nil) -> String {
        if let template = template {
            let df = DateFormatter.with(template: template)
            
            return df.string(from: self)
        }
        else {
            return globalDateFormatter.string(from: self)
        }
    }
}

// Here you can set default template for DateFormatter
public let globalDateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter.with(template: "y-M-d")

public extension DateFormatter {
    static func with(template: String ) -> DateFormatter {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = template
        return df
    }
}
```

Comment: This is crazy good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:myNSDateInstance];
NSInteger year = [components year];
// NSInteger month = [components month];
NSString *yearStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", year];
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your own utility for format your date required date format 
for eg.

```
NSString * stringFromDate(NSDate *date)  
 {   NSDateFormatter *formatter
    [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM ∕ dd ∕ yyyy, hh꞉mm a"];    
    return [formatter stringFromDate:date]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#ios #swift #convertDateinString

Simply just do like this to "convert date into string" as per format you passed:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY" // pass formate here
        
let myString = formatter.string(from: date) // this will convert Date in String
```

Note: You can specify different formats such like `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, `"yyyy"`, `"MM"` etc...

Answer (score 0):

## Update for iOS 15

iOS 15 now supports calling `.formatted` on `Date` objects directly without an explicit `DateFormatter`.

### Example for common formats

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/formatstyle/3798886-init)

```
date.formatted() // 6/8/2021, 7:30 PM
date.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .complete) // 19:30
date.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .standard) // 07:30 PM
date.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened) // 7:30 PM
date.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .omitted)
```

### Alternative syntax

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/formatstyle)

```
// We can also specify each DateComponent separately by chaining modifiers.
date.formatted(.dateTime.weekday(.wide).day().month().hour().minute())
// Tuesday, Jun 8, 7:30 pm

// Answer to specific question
date.formatted(.dateTime.year())
```

Answer (score 0):

for Objective-C:

```objectivec
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy";
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

for Swift:

```
let now = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
let dateString = formatter.string(from: now)
```

That's a good website for [nsdateformatter](https://nsdateformatter.com/).You can preview date strings with different `DateFormatter` in different local.

[image]