# How to convert NSDate to NSString as 2012-10-17T10:13:15.343+02:00

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert NSDate to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring)

UPDATE: WHERE IS THE DIRECT ANSWER FROM THE DUPLICATE QUESTION
Please provide me the link for this answer.

How to convert NSDate to NSString like this

```
2012-10-17T10:13:15.343+02:00
```

Comment: We can help you better if you tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 1):

So something along the lines of this: "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"

For more information: [Date Formatting Guide-Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

Comment: Why did u put all these `'` in there?