# NSString compare is throwing exception SIGABT

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I have following code, where I'm comparing two string but its throwing exception.

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {
NSLog(@"calendarMonthView didSelectDate %@",d);
//[self papulateTable];
//[table reloadData];
 //[self performSelector:@selector(papulateTable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
NSString *tempDate = (NSString*)d;
NSString *selectedDate = @"2013-02-04 00:00:00 +0000";
if([tempDate isEqualToString:selectedDate])
{
  flagtoCheckSelectedCalendarDate = 1;
}
if(flagtoCheckSelectedCalendarDate == 1)
{
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
if(flagtoCheckSelectedCalendarDate == 2)
{
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
//[table reloadData];
```

}

Could any one please suggest.Thanks.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: I think the problem is in the line NSString *tempDate = (NSString*)d; If you want to check two dates then NSDate have that feature use that.

Comment: Who is upvoting this idiotic question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting an `NSDate` object to `NSString` does not make it a string. To compare dates, you're going to have to transform the `NSString` into an `NSDate` using an `NSDateFormatter`. After that, you can use NSDate's instance method `isEqualToDate:` for your comparison.

```
NSString *selectedDate = @"2013-02-04 00:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *actualDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:selectedDate];


if ([actualDate isEqualToDate:d]) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. My "d" is comming in "2013-02-04 04:30:00 IST" format.And, the compair fails.So,its not going inside if statement. Note: I'm using Calendar to selet my date.

Comment: It doesn't matter what format was used to create a date, in the end you have 2 NSDate objects that represent a date (in any format). Please explain your problem in depth.

Comment: Problem is: after using "NSDate *actualDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:selectedDate];" My date is showing "actualDate = 2013-01-04".How it is going back to Jan month after using dateFormatter?

Comment: Thanks for help. I just change the format to : [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss zzzz"]; Because, my time zone is GMT+5.30.Now its working.

Answer (score 1):

`d` is of type `NSDate` and not `NSString`, therefore `-isEqualToString:` results in a crash.
You shouldn't compare strings here, but the dates. Use NSDate's `-compare:` method and change

```
NSString *selectedDate = @"2013-02-04 00:00:00 +0000";
```

to

```
NSDate *selectedDate = [NSDate ...];
```

Comment: Could you pl. tell me what should I write between "[NSDate ...];"

Comment: That depends on which date you want to compare to. You can use NSCalendar to create a date on a specific day/month/year or convert the string to a date using what @Stavash posted.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `NSDate` and `NSString`. You would need to change the `NSDate` to string using a date formatter first.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting an NSDate object to NSString without converting it. You will have to format the NSDate as a string into your expected date format before you can compare it with your selectedDate. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring) for examples