# NSdateFormatter making assigned date to a month back

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm using NSDateFormatter like following:

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {
NSLog(@"calendarMonthView didSelectDate %@",d);
NSDate *tempDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];// = d;
NSString *selectedDate = @"2013-02-01 00:00:00 +0000";
//NSString *selectedDate = @"2013-02-04";
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
tempDate = [dateformatter dateFromString:selectedDate];
//if([tempDate compare:d])
if([tempDate isEqualToDate:d])
{
  flagtoCheckSelectedCalendarDate = 1;
}
if(flagtoCheckSelectedCalendarDate == 1)
{
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
if(flagtoCheckSelectedCalendarDate == 2)
{
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
//[table reloadData];

}
```

Why is this output me wrong date?Where I'm going wrong??Please suggest.

Comment: please show the output you are getting and tell us what behaviour you expected to see instead

Comment: Does you know the datformatter of NSString *selectedDate used previously. Need to use same other wise it will redirect null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644329/nsstring-compair-is-throwing-exception-sigabt/14644440#comment20461920_14644440

Comment: I know this is not related to your question. However, it is not adivsable calling viewDidLoad on your own. You should leave that to the API. If things happen in viewDidLoad which you like to call again later on your own, then move that to a third method (like configureView) and call configureView instead. You can of course call configureView from your viewDidLoad too, to avoid and duplication of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ZZZZ"];

---

The DD in your formatter string is wrong.  Capital D is day number within the year. You want d.

> d:1~31 (0 padded Day of Month)
>
> D:1~366 (0 padded Day of Year)