# NSDateFormatter stringFromDate: returns incorrect date on December 31st

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

According to unixtimestamp.com - at midnight on the 31st of December 2013 the timestamp was 1388448000.

So why is this happening?

in `ViewController.m`:

```
NSDateFormatter *titleFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
_titleFormatter = titleFormatter;
```

in LLDB:

```
(lldb) po [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1388448000]
2013-12-31 00:00:00 +0000
(lldb) p [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1388448000]
(id) $1 = 0x16e5c0b0
(lldb) po [self.titleFormatter stringFromDate:$1]
December 2014
```

Comment: How did you set the date format?

Comment: I'm just curious as to how the format got set to "MMMM YYYY".

Answer (score 6):

My mistake. Somewhere in the code I had:

```
[self.titleFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM YYYY"]
```

Of course, YYYY should be yyyy in this case. [Difference between 'YYYY' and 'yyyy' in NSDateFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter)

Comment: +1 for admitting your mistake.  (This is why we're constantly telling folks to show us ALL the code.)