# NSDateFormatter returns nil with format YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ

Tags: objective-c, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get the `NSDate` from a string with the following format 'YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' using the `NSDateFormatter`. The `NSDateFormatter` returns always `nil`. Here is how I tried to do that:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-08-09T18:30:00+02:00"];
```

Comment: Hint: The date string does not end with a literal 'Z'. - And 'YYYY' should probably be 'yyyy'.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you need to escape characters like : - in '' marks

Comment: Hint:  Consult the [date format string spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

that would be a better formatter.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date format string should be as follows:

```
@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ"
```

Note the lower cased `'yyyy'`. The uppercase Y means "Week of Year" based calendar.

See this answer: [Difference between 'YYYY' and 'yyyy' in NSDateFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter?rq=1) and the Unicode standard for more info: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns