# Weird behavior of NSDate, NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am formatting a NSDate in my application. Using below code:

```
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    NSString* currentDateTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];

    NSLog(@"CurrentDateTime:%@", currentDateTime);

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    currentDateTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSLog(@"CurrentDateTime 1 :%@", currentDateTime);

    [dateFormatter release];
```

But this work fine for whole year but fails after 27-Dec. It adds a year after format the date of 27-Dec or above. Only when we use the `"YYYY"` instead of `"yyyy"`. Its again works fine after the year change. So please can you suggest the reason behind this.

Comment: You can find the answer in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer for your question is below

```
"YYYY" is week-based calendar year.

"yyyy" is ordinary calendar year.
```

For more details

[Difference between 'yyyy' and 'YYYY'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter?rq=1)

[Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)