# timeIntervalSince1970 conversion returns the wrong year in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdateformatter, unix-timestamp

I'm facing a problem that `timeIntervalSince1970` returns the wrong year.

Here is my code

```
func unixToDateString(timeStamp: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStamp)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier:Locale.current.identifier)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/YYYY"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

and these are my results

```
unixToDateString(timeStamp: 1505896961.0)
```

returns

```
09/20/2017
```

which is correct

but,

```
unixToDateString(timeStamp: 1546214400.0)
unixToDateString(timeStamp: 4133894400.0)
```

returns

```
12/31/2019
12/31/2101
```

they both return extra one year according to [Epoch Unix Time Stamp Converter](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)

```
1546214400.0 = 12/31/2018
4133894400.0 = 12/31/2100
```

Does anyone have the same situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the date format uses "Year (of "Week of Year")" (`YYYY`) but the result you are expecting is "Calendar Year" (`yyyy`).

After changing the date format to `"MM/dd/yyyy"`, I'm seeing results that you are expecting (the years 2018 and 2100).

---

You can see both `Y` and `y` listed in the [Unicode Standard Date Field Symbol Table](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns). In their example, the Year of "Week of Year" (1997) is also one more than the Calendar Year (1996).

The [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) also brings up the same problem and points out that one should typically use the calendar date (`yyyy`):

> A common mistake is to use `YYYY`. `yyyy` specifies the calendar year whereas `YYYY` specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, `yyyy` and `YYYY` yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

Comment: Thank you so much and the details :)
You solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

you use YYYY instead of yyyy.
Check this page for detail. ^^

[Difference between 'YYYY' and 'yyyy' in NSDateFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I didn't notice that YYYY and yyyy are different