# Why does sdf.format(date) converts 2018-12-30 to 2019-12-30 in java?

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert date to string but the year 2018 gets changed to 2019 while conversion.

I tried with different dates, it works. It only fails for December 30 and December 31 2018.

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
Date date = fmt.parse("2018-12-30");
String date2 = fmt.format(date);
```

Expected result: 2018-12-30

Actual result: 2019-12-30

Comment: What is `sdf`??

Comment: `fmt` seems to work just fine, produces a `Date` of `Sun Dec 30 00:00:00 AEDT 2018`.  What is `sdf` setup as? Also, you really should be using the `java.time` API instead of these out-of-date classes

Comment: I just updated the sdf declaration

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter. If you google for "SimpleDateFormat YYYY vs yyyy", then you'll find several links, which say: "Don't use YYYY".

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Case-sensitive

Uppercase `YYYY` means year of a week-based year rather than a calendar year (lowercase `yyyy`).

So you are seeing a feature, not a bug. The second to the last day of 2018 is in the first week of 2019 according to the definition of a week used by `SimpleDateFormat`. That definition varies by `Locale`.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `LocalDate`

The `LocalDate` class is appropriate to your string inputs.

```
String input = "2019-12-30" ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;
```

Comment: changing the sdf format to yyyy worked.

Comment: i does, @Dookoto_Sea. I still think you should do yourself and those maintaining your code after you the favour of not using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Where sdf is setup?? Just use `fmt` it will works fine. Try Following.

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = fmt.parse("2018-12-30");
String date2 = fmt .format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to format the date again with `SimpleDateFormat`. Just use as follows.

**Date format required : 2019-12-30**

**The appropriate date format specified will be : *yyyy.MM.dd* (yyyy : Represents full year)**

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2018-12-30");
String sDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```