# Wrong output with Java SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, format

I need to parse a date from this format: **WeekDay Month DD HH:MM:SS GFT YYYY** to this format: **YYY/MM/DD**, and this is what I tried to do:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD");
String conclusionDate = format.format(filter.getConclusionDate());
```

But there is something wrong going on. For example, when I try to format this date: "**Thu Sep 01 00:00:00 GFT 2016**", what I get is "**2016/09/245**" instead of "**2016/09/01**"

The weirdest is that it seems to be happening only with months different than JANUARY. When I try another random example like "**Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GFT 2000**" I get exactly what I want: " **2000/01/01** ". It still formats correctly if I vary the day field

But when I change it to be another month, like february (" **Tue Feb 01 00:00:00 GFT 2000** "), I get it wrong: " **2000/02/32** "

Why is it?

**OBS**: Before you ask: Yes, I have checked and the date that is returned in **getConclusionDate()** is exactly in the expected format **WeekDay Month DD HH:MM:SS GFT YYYY** .

Comment: *For example, when I try to format this date: "Thu Sep 01 00:00:00 GFT 2016"* You'd need *parse* that first. How is that done?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D is the day in the year, d is the day of the month.  You want YYY/dd/MM https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: It’s still not correct. And you don’t want to use `SimpleDateFormat` at all (for how it’s not correct see [Why does sdf.format(date) converts 2018-12-30 to 2019-12-30 in java? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620110/why-does-sdf-formatdate-converts-2018-12-30-to-2019-12-30-in-java)).