# Swift Date formating changes to next month when using end of month data?

Tags: swift

I live by end of month dates such as "2019-02-28 23:59:59"

print when I print out that date it tells me "Mar-2019".  No it is still "Feb-2019"

```
print(dt1.toString(dateFormat: "MMM-YYYY")
```

I do use SwiftDate. I also get this issue with the DateFormatter().

so instead of clean code I end up having to  subtracting a day to get the correct month-year to display.

Why?

Comment: Did you remember to set the `timeZone` of the date formatter to your own timezone?

Comment: YYYY (with capital Y) is most probably *not* what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15133549/1187415.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `Timezone` & `date` format properly as below,

```
let string = "2019-02-28 23:59:59"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.timeZone = .current
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date = df.date(from: string)
print(date?.description(with: .current)) //Thursday, February 28, 2019 at 11:59:59 PM Gulf Standard Time
df.dateFormat = "MMM-yyyy"
print(df.string(from: date!)) // Feb-2019
```

Comment: I will suggest give it a read [Understanding Dates](http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html).

Comment: I see what everyone is saying, thank you.  I have been using SwiftDate because I thought is was simpler that using all the Calendar and DateFormatter() codes. Adding the locals and regions with SwiftDate offsets the simplicity I thought.  I still am not sure which it the best approach?  The apps will be international so that is another variable to consider.   Anyone have thoughts on SwiftDate vs pure Swift?  Cheers.

Comment: @diogenes I think its a very helpful library and it saves time. But for better use, one should know the basic date functions. If you have read the above article i shared then it will help you a lot using this library.