# Java-Zoned time not returning correct year

Tags: java, android

Due to the new year,I detected a bug in my project.
I am showing date and time in my order history using the following code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a MM/dd/YY", Locale.US).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
String formattedOrderDate = formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of(order.timeZone)).format(order.order.pickupAt);
textView.setText(formattedOrderDate );
```

Here are the values received from server:

```
order.order.pickupAt = {ZonedDateTime@8390} "2020-01-02T17:50Z"
order.timeZone = "America/Denver"
```

But the output is not showing the **perfect year** for the end of December:

[image]

As you can clearly see, **year 2019 is showing as 2020**.

**But it is only showing for the last of December.Another order from mid of December is showing the correct date(year).**

[image]

I am not able to detect what is going wrong over here.I am suspecting that this might be due to the timezone(America/Denver).But I have changed the timezone to my local timezone,still it is showing 2020 instead of 2019.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15133617/10182897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YY` is for **week-based calendar year** and `yy` is for **calendar year**. Last `few days` of December was actually the **first week of 2020**, so it is showing `2020` for those days.

Change your code to use `yy`, then it will show correct year -

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a MM/dd/yy", Locale.US).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use yy instead of YY

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a MM/dd/yy", Locale.US).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
String formattedOrderDate = formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of(order.timeZone)).format(order.order.pickupAt);
textView.setText(formattedOrderDate );
```