# BirtDateTime.addDay returns wrong year around new years eve

Tags: eclipse, birt

I have a birt report with two parameters, startDate and endDate (which are both text-fields / strings). They are prefilled with yesterday and yesterday + ' 23:59:59', so the format looks like `2019-12-20` and `2019-12-20 23:59:59`.

The function for this is `Formatter.format(BirtDateTime.addDay(BirtDateTime.today(), -1), "YYYY-MM-dd")` and `Formatter.format(BirtDateTime.addDay(BirtDateTime.today(), -1), "YYYY-MM-dd 23:59:59")` respectively.

This works fine until the end of this year. The generated dates look like this:

```
| BirtDateTime.today() | Generated date |
| -------------------- | -------------- |
| 2019-12-29           | 2019-12-28     |
| 2019-12-30           | 2020-12-29     |
| 2019-12-31           | 2020-12-30     |
| 2020-01-01           | 2020-12-31     |
| 2019-01-02           | 2020-01-01     |
```

As you can see, from 2019-12-30 until 2020-01-01 the generated dates from the addDay function have the wrong year. My first guess is that it has to do something with the calendar weeks (because a new week starts on 2019-12-30, but on the 2nd of January everything is fine again...

I can reproduce this if I replace BirtDateTime.today() with a fixed string `"2019-12-31"` or similar. If I use another year, let's say 2018, only the 2019-01-01 will return a wrong date (2019-31-12 instead of 2018-12-31).

Is there something I haven't seen or came anybody across this behaviour? If it matters, I'm using birt 2019-03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`YYYY` specifies using the week year. Use should instead using `yyyy` to simply use the year on the actual day.

As you can see in the [`BirtDateTime.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/birt/blob/master/data/org.eclipse.birt.core.script.function/src/org/eclipse/birt/core/script/function/bre/BirtDateTime.java) source that under the hood the `SimpleDateFormat` is used for the formatting.
The Javadoc of [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) says

> Letter | Date or Time Component
>
> y | Year
>
> Y | Week year

Comment: Didn't know the difference until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly the same problem.

As **Number(BirtDateTime.diffDay(BirtDateTime.today(), BirtDateTime.addDay(BirtDateTime.today(), -10)))** was correct (-10) the problem was elsewhere.

Using 'yyyy' instead of 'YYYY' fixed the problem.
See [yyyy vs YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter).