# Google Spreadsheet month is being decremented by 1

Tags: java, android-studio, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am receiving date in my android application from google spreadsheet through appscript and i am receiving this data in `yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` this format and I dont know why because in spreadsheet date is in `dd-MM-YYYY` this format but the main issue is when receiving date from spreadsheet month `MM` is decremented by one and also if it is `01` it becomes `31` which creates an error in my application while parsing the format.
Please tell me how to stop this decrementing of month value.

Comment: Can you provide your code? How to you parse the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you retrieve and send the data with Apps Script, but

**Apps Script features the method [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)**

that allows to format the data before processing it further.

**Sample:**

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var date = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+2", "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

- It is important to specify the time zone, because otherwise the date might be retrieved / passed incorrectly.
- Also: if you use `YYYY` instead of `yyyy` - ming that it would be the [calendar-based year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter).