# Value of type 'Date' has no member 'format' & Value of type 'Date' has no member 'hours'

Tags: ios, swift, calendarkit, xcode12.3

I have added CalendarKit in my project using swift package Manager, I tried with cocoapods as well but still I am getting the below errors:
I have added `import CalendarKit` as well.
**1)  Value of type 'Date' has no member 'format'**

```
let timezone = TimeZone.ReferenceType.default
        var info:[String] = ["Booking Id: \(bookingDetails.bookingID ?? -1)", "Booking Type: \(bookingDetails.bookingType!)"]
        info.append("Booking From : \(begining.format(with: "dd.MM.YYYY", timeZone: timezone)) \nBooking To : \(ending.format(with: "dd.MM.YYYY", timeZone: timezone))")
        info.append("Timing: \(begining.format(with: "HH:mm")) - \(ending.format(with: "HH:mm"))")
        info.append("Status: \(status)\n")
```

**2) Value of type 'Date' has no member 'hours'**

```
 if indexPath.section == 1 {
                    selectedbookingRecord = self.upcomingBookings![indexPath.row] as BookingInfoList
                    if let bookingStartDateTime = selectedbookingRecord?.bookingFrom {
                        if (bookingStartDateTime.toDate()?.hours(from: Date()))! < 24 {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                Alert().showAlert(ALERT_TITLE, message: GlobalConstants.CANNOT_DELETE_BOOKING, okButtonTitle: ALERT_OK_TITLE, CompletionHandler: nil, View: self)
                            }
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apart from your issue `YYYY` is wrong.

Comment: ok so what should I use instead of YYYY?

Comment: Lowercase `yyyy`. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter

Comment: That's from the ReadMe, but I don't find in their github the extension on `Date` nor the method (on another object) `format(with: String)`. That ReadMe is misleading, or maybe outdated (did that exist beforehand)? And I don't know where you took `hours(from:` from? It's not in their github.

Comment: Ok. After some digging. It had previously a dependency on DateSwiftTools which had     `func format(with dateFormat: String) -> String` https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools/blob/83342e09297a33558d64ea696c3a5e0aae5a8f2a/DateToolsSwift/DateTools/Date%2BFormat.swift#L140 (same for `hours(from:) in Date+Comparators.swift)`. The ReadMe is not up to date at all.

Comment: Yes @Larme even I can't see those functions, I have 2 years old source code that's why I tagged calendarkit so may be the author can help about this issue. But It works fine on the developer's system who developed. Do you think something I need to add in Build Phase ->run script?

Comment: I did some digging and found out where they were implemented. But they are only in the ReadMe, so I think that's just an outdated ReadMe, shouldn't affect the real code. If you still need the methods, I pointed out the other GitHub needed `DateSwiftTools`.

Comment: @Larme ok, So did you find any replacement functions for format and hours?

Comment: Use the other github. It has a podspec too. If you had that into you real code (and not only in a ReadMe), you should keep the old version of CalendarKit. Else, you might have stronger answers on their GitHub issue.

Comment: Is it possible to get that version of podspec which has those methods?

Comment: It has been removed there https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/commit/3388a3130f32134eb9cb702ec602fb51ceb48e0e#diff-1d0ac5640b81b88873b83c776bd276c6813adfbd3f6ff49515bc0d36ff87494e use a version corresponding just before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the provided code has been developed with the older version of `CalendarKit` which had a dependency on `DateToolsSwift`. Now, when the dependency has been removed, the code you've provided doesn't compile.

In order to resolve your issue, either use an older version of CalendarKit (not greater than `0.14.0`, e.g. `0.13.14` would do just fine),

or, just install and import [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools) independently to the files where you're using that framework.

Comment: Hello @richard I am getting below error while trying this version:   [!] Unable to find a specification for `CalendarKit~> 0.13.14`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Comment: Installing DateTools is a better approach, since you'll get all of the newest updates of CalendarKit.
I also suggest "fixing" the version of the library used to `0.14.x` if the project is only in maintenance.