# Date formatter not changing properly

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

The date I'm having is this..

`2021-03-05T12:21:18`

But I want it in `dd-MM-yyyy` format. This is what I did for that...

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: self.Due_Date) //self.Due_Date is 2021-03-05T12:21:18
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"                 
self.Due_Date = dateFormatter.string(from: date2!) //CRASH HERE
```

But I get `date2` as nil. So the code crashes at `self.Due_Date = dateFormatter.string(from: date2!)`

What could be the reason for this...?

Comment: Not related to your question but `YYYY` is wrong. `Y` is for `YearForWeekOfYear`. What you need is `yyyy`

Comment: `print(self.Due_Date)` before parsing it. I guess its value is not `"2021-03-05T12:21:18"`

Comment: Actually @LeoDabus its value is `2021-03-05T12:21:18`. Hence I gave the formatter as `"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` in the first line of code.

Comment: I have seen date strings with a carriage return added. Look closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The “yyyy” represents the calendar year of the date while the “YYYY” represents the year of the week.

for detail information, please see this [Difference between 'YYYY' and 'yyyy' in NSDateFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter)

```
let getInputString = "2021-03-05T12:21:18"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        if let getInputDate = dateFormatter.date(from:getInputString){
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            let getoutputString = dateFormatter.string(from: getInputDate)
        }
```

Note : as per @LeoDabus guidelines please ensure the self.Due_Date is empty or not before start the conversion.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It would result in a different year in some cases.

Comment: @LeoDabus - yeah correct , I will update the answer

Comment: Also make sure to set the locale to "EN_US_POSIX" otherwise it might fail depending on the device 12/24hour locale/settings.