# Swift String value converted into strange Date value

Tags: swift, dateformatter

```
extension Date {
    func toString() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, Y (E)"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}

extension String {
    func toDate() -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, Y (E)"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)!
    }
}
```

That is my code.
I want to convert my string value into a right date value. The results i’m getting are totally different form what i want.

Here is an example:

```
String : September 09, 2021 (Thu)
Converted Date : 2020-12-24 00:00:00 +0000
```

I want it to be like this:

```
Converted Date : September 09, 2021 (Thu) (or 2021-09-09 00:00:00 +0000)
```

Comment: Where does 'MMMM dd, Y (E)' come from?

Comment: @ElTomato that was just the format i want. date to string is working. but string to date isn't

Comment: Change `Y` to `y` or `yyyy`. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, Y (E)"
```

To:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy (E)"
```

You pass the full year in String: September 09, 2021 (Thu) so you need to get yyyy to the right way.

```
extension String {
    func toDate() -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy (E)"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)!
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here you can do what you want:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy (E)" // here is your foramt
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "September 09, 2021 (Thu)") else {
   fatalError()
}
print(date) // output: 2021-09-09 00:00:00 +0000
```

Note that, the time zone which you choosed, should matched to your device time zone.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace Your Function with Following Code**

```
extension Date {
    func toString() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy (E)"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}

extension String {
    func toDate() -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy (E)"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)!
    }
}
```

*There was slight variance of in your `dateFormat` in your `toDate()` Function*

- Replaced **MMM** from **MMMM**
- Replaced **yyyy** from **Y**

**I don't know why it was showing different date but now it should work**