# iphone Date from string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have one string

```
NSString *timeStr =@"04:57PM";
```

This is my date formatter

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
```

Converting NSString to NSDate

```
NSDate *date=[dateFormat dateFromString:timeStr];
NSLog(@"date is :::%@",date);
```

The output in the Log is

```
date is :::1970-01-01 11:27:00 +0000.
```

Can i know What to do to get the output as
 **`date is :::04:57PM`**.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring

Comment: You have created date, but printing date1. Is it correct? :)

Comment: it is date..now i edited help me

Comment: you can set dateformat object to timezone then u will get exact result what u expected. [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

Comment: just do `NSLog(@"date is :::%@", timeStr);`, why do you need to convert the string to date to print it back as a string in the same format it was previously?

Comment: @sugan ..i need datefromString convertion but not stringfromdate

Comment: @tkanzakic  my label shows time ..i have time button next to label .on click of time i need to show time picker with the time in the label.so to set date to picker i need NSDate instance.So i need to convert it to date.

Comment: please do not give negative vote. may be for you guys it looks like a simple question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same `NSDateFormatter` and the `stringFromDate` method to get the same string. Your date will probably be different because you haven't set the locale on your `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The reason why you can't is that internally `NSDate` is nothing more than a simple double representing the amount of time that has passed since a reference point.  It only becomes 4:57 PM when you want to convert it *back into a string* using `NSDateFormatter`

Think of it this way, a point in time is the same all over the world.  It is just measured differently depending on where you are.  `NSDate` is that point, and `NSDateFormatter` helps you get the final measurement.  It will always log according to GMT.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer..i have one question that is....i have label shows time ..i have time button next to label .on click of time i need to show time picker with the time in the label.so to set date to picker i need NSDate from NSString instance.So i need to convert it to date..How to do this

Comment: You already did.  What is the problem?  Did you forget to set a timezone on your date picker?

Answer (score -2):

instead of this

`NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];`

Use this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
```

Comment: Why?  That is not the correct format.  There is no space.

Answer (score -2):

You try the following code:

Replace

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
```

with

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why?  That is not the correct format, there is a leading zero and no space.

Comment: @borrrden please check this link: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns     This describes the format unicodes.

Comment: I know, I've seen it many times.  It is proof that you are wrong.

Comment: So please let me know, what is the exact format?

Comment: His format is correct.  The format is not the problem he is having.