# IOS: Converting NSDate to NSString gives nil value

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Where is my mistake? I have an NSDate with this format (data: 14/05/2013 10:52:27) and I have to obtain an NSString.

```
   NSLog(@"Data: %@",lettureObj.data);

   NSDateFormatter *outputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [outputDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
   NSString *data  = [outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:lettureObj.data];
```

Comment: What is the result of first statement.

Comment: data: 14/05/2013 10:52:27

Comment: code is fine it should work and it is working for me.

Comment: If I use  NSString *data= lettureObj.data It works good but I have an XCode warning

Comment: maybe is the first assigning lettureObj.data was wrong....

Comment: incompatible pointer ....to NSDate from NSString

Comment: @Amar: Incompatible pointer type `stringFromDate` expects date object

Comment: lettureObj.data is NSString instead of NSDate, are you doing it right? Or do you want to convert NSString to NSDate instead?

Comment: @AlessandroMattiuzzi: What is the data type of `lettureObj.data` ? Are you sure its `NSDate` object?

Comment: @Alessandro Mattiuzzi: Can u give what "NSLog(@"Data: %@",lettureObj.data);" is printing?

Comment: lettureObj.data is a NSdate but i assign it:            lettureObj.data = dateString;

Comment: You please provide what it is printing

Comment: data: 14/05/2013 10:52:27

Comment: Then your date formatter should work properly. My doubt "lettureObj.data" may not be an NSDate object. To check that please try the line of code given. if([lettureObj.data isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) NSLog(@"Its NSDate Object"); else NSLog(@"Its not an NSDate Object");

Comment: SOLVED BRO. The problem was that I assign an NSString to lettureObj.data when i did ettureObj.data = dateString.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert NSDate to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the lettureObj.data is NSString and what you need is to convert it into date primarly to have an NSDate object

Comment: yes I think this is the problem...but in my h. file i defined it       @property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *data;

Comment: Now I do  lettureObj.data = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]; AND WORKS

Comment: Thats it :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

use following functions

```
//*********************************Convert String into Date **********************

- (NSDate*) convertStringToDate:(NSString*)dateStr dateformat:(NSString*)dateformat
{
    // Convert string to date object
    //dateformat like :@"yyyy-MM-dd"]
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateformat];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];  
    [dateFormatter release];//For NON-ARC
    return date;
}

//*********************************Convert date into String **********************

- (NSString*) convertDateToString:(NSDate*)date  dateformat:(NSString*)dateformat
{
    // Convert date object to desired output format
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat1 setDateFormat:dateformat];
    NSString *dateStr = [dateFormat1 stringFromDate:date];  
    [dateFormat1 release];//For NON-ARC

    return dateStr;
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: It's the same thing I do boss. But not works for me here....

Comment: make sure that `lettureObj.data` is a NSDate

Comment: @AlessandroMattiuzzi: These conversion methods should work fine provided you are passing correct data type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   NSString *strTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lettureObj.data];

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
   NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:strTemp];
   [dateFormat release];


   NSDateFormatter *outputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [outputDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

  NSString *data  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
```