# how to get [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.Row] as string

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSString *dateString=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[timeit objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: and why you alloc string there is no need it.

Comment: What kind of object are you getting from the array?

Comment: That depends on the type of objects that exist in your array.

Comment: thank u any way  
sorry for annoying , this code work correctly when array includes are strings , but it's doesn't work when array are dates of time , so what could i do please , i need to get my date array as strings

Comment: Your code works for any object. Though you should never do this for anything except debugging. If you want to convert dates, use `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: this is my code of dates array and i want this array display as subtitle on table view cell .

Answer (score -4, accepted):

no need to alloc and init

```
NSString *dateString=[NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@", [timeit objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: This assumes the array contains an `NSString` object. We don't know if that is true or not.

Comment: yes thats right. then try my new edited answer

Comment: Now you are simply repeating the code the OP had. What's the point of that?

Comment: thank uu, also i need to gets my array that have dates , so what could i do please :)

Comment: Down voter what is your problem man??

Comment: @user3354963 did you down vote it??

Comment: I donwvoted because your answer simply repeats the code in the original question. There is no point to such an answer.

Comment: just check it man he is allocing and init the string and i have used StringWithFormat method

Comment: this two are totally different things. just check it

Comment: That doesn't matter. It still does the same thing. Calling `stringWithFormat:` is the same as calling `alloc/init/autorelease`. The end result is the same, especially under ARC.

Comment: of course no i did check mark am new on stackover flow i don't have permission to make vote ,Mr @mohitpopat , really thank uuu , i never make vote down for any one help me

Comment: its ok is it worked for you?

Comment: @user3354963 no need to say thank you. i m here to help others and to learn something new.

Comment: thank it's work in array includes string but does not work on array include dates .

Comment: his is my code of dates array and i want this array display as subtitle on table view cell .

Comment: ok do you wants full date (date & time) or you need only date??

Comment: NSMutableArray*timeit=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSDate date]]; NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; NSString *plistPathTime=[documentsPath stringByAppendingString:@"Data.plist"]; [timeit addObjectsFromArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPathTime]]; [timeit writeToFile:plistPathTime atomically: YES];

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `NSString *dateString=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Is it working?

Comment: Your welcome. We are always here to help others and getting help too :)

Comment: sorry for annoying
 , this code work correctly when array includes are strings , but it's doesn't work when array are dates of time , so what could i do please , i need to get my date array as strings

Comment: try my new edited code. StringWithFormat is used to convert any object into String

Comment: Please check out Convert NSDate to NSString: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring

Comment: Hope, It will may helpful to you.

Comment: thank u i will see it now