# Trying to get the current date as just month, day and year

Tags: ios

I'm using the folowing code to get the date as a string

```
strStartDate.text=[mOnTimeApp->cDate descriptionWithLocale:nil];
```

It works but has the hour, minute and second.  Is there a way to just get the Month, day and year as a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert NSDate to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing **nil** into **descriptionWithLocale:** is the same as calling **description** on an instance of **NSDate**. [NSDate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188--descriptionWithLocale_) has the following to say about **descriptionWithLocale:**

> **Return Value**
>
> A string representation of the receiver, using the given locale, or if
>   the locale argument is nil, in the international format YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS ±HHMM, where ±HHMM represents the time zone offset in hours
>   and minutes from GMT (for example, “2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600”)

You can configure an instance of **NSDateFormatter** to represent the desired format and then use the method **stringFromDate:** passing in your **NSDate** object -

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
strStartDate.text = [formatter stringFromDate:mOnTimeApp->cDate];
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this why you are looking for?

```
+ (NSString*)getAbsoluteDateAndTimeFromString:(NSNumber*)formattedTime
{
    long long ts = [formattedTime longLongValue];
    ts /= 1000;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:ts];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy h:mm a"];

    return[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```