# Show Date with DateFormatter

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I'm looking for a way to display the current date in a label with Swift 3. 
Currently I'm using DateFormatter.dateFormat but the only output I get is

> dd.MM.yyyy

Here is the line of code:

```
lbl_Date.text = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "MMddyyyy", options: 0, locale: NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "de-AT") as Locale)
```

And my expected output for today should be:

> 11.12.2016

I know that I can get the time with the dateTimeComponents but I haven't figured out how I can get only the date (day, month and year) in my label:

```
// get the current date and time
    let currentDateTime = Date()

    // get the user's calendar
    let userCalendar = Calendar.current

    // choose which date and time components are needed
    let requestedComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [
        .year,
        .month,
        .day,
        .hour,
        .minute,
        .second
    ]

    // get the components
    let dateTimeComponents = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponents, from: currentDateTime)
```

What is there the cleanest way to display the current date in my label?

Comment: That function is to create a date format. That for that is then used to render a date into a string. Look at any of these thousands of similar questions on stack overflow to find out how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert NSDate to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget `Calendar` and `DateComponents`. Use `DateFormatter`

```
let currentDateTime = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
```

If you want a fixed format set the `dateFormat` to

```
formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
```

alternatively if you want a format depending on the current locale set `timeStyle` and `dateStyle` rather than the `format` property

```
formatter.timeStyle = .none
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
```

Now get the string

```
let dateString = formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works fine and is also really simple!