# How convert DateTime to string

Tags: swift, swift4

I get from server response in DateTime like this :

> 2019-04-24T16:25:02.557Z

and I would like only in String:

> 2019-04-23

How can I do this?

my code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ"

let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"
let d = job.postedAt
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: d) {
    let k = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)
    destinationVC.createdJob = k
} else {
    print("There was an error decoding the string")
}
```

Comment: This already described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring

Comment: It doesn't work and there is objective c, I write in swift 4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert NSDate to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try,

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let d = "2019-04-24T16:25:02.557Z"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: d) {
    let k = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)

    print(k)
} else {
    print("There was an error decoding the string")
}
```

Your dateFormatter.dateFormat should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` and your dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat should be `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: You don't want quotes around the `Z`, or if you do, you'd have to manually specify the time zone to GMT/UTC/Zulu. It's easiest to remove the quotes around the `Z` in the format string. Also, if you're going to manually create a formatter like this for this ISO8601 string, you must set the local of the first formatter (but not the second one) to `en_US_POSIX`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the `2019-04-24T16:25:02.557Z` to a `Date` object, you'd use:

```
let iso8601DateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
iso8601DateFormatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
guard let date = iso8601DateFormatter.date(from: "2019-04-24T16:25:02.557Z") else { return }
```

And then to output only a date string in the UI, with no time, you'd use something like:

```
let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
let result = outputFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
func stringFromDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm" //yyyy
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```